# Cocos2d-x CCDirector -> pass around or call when needed?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, parameter-passing, cocos2d-x

I have a conceptual question about the use if CCDirector and other shared Cocos2d-x objects.

One common thing that is always done is:

```
CCSize s = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
```

I usually just pass `s` around where needed instead of re-calling `CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();`

Is this what others do? Or do they just re-issue the call where needed?

is there a cost benefit to passing around versus just calling it where needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define MIDSCREEN  ccp(CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize().width/2, CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize().height/2)
#define WINSIZE    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize()
#define WINHEIGHT  CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize().height
#define WINWIDTH   CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize().width
```

Comment: Holy Cow! Great idea. +100.

Comment: so basically, your answer is call where needed?

Comment: Given that the sharedDirector()->getWinsize() call just returns the size variable without calculating anything, there's really no point in doing it once and passing it around. You'd just be doubling the memory use. Making it a macro makes it easy. He asked what others do - that's what I do.